# How this can work for multiple ring buffer

Tags: geopandas

Let you tell me how to extend this capability to multiple ring buffer

Comment: Add a code attempt or your question will get closed. You want to multiple ring buffer your data?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 2):

This will create a non overlapping multiring buffer with number of rings (nrings) and ring distance (ringdist) as inputs:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r"C:/GIS/data/testdata/Delauney/20points.shp")
crs = df.crs #Save the crs. It is lost in the processing.

def multiringbuffer(df, nrings, ringdist):
    """Buffers an input dataframes geometry nring (number of rings) times, with a distance between rings of ringdist and
returns a list of non overlapping buffers"""

    rings=[] #A list to hold the individual buffers
    for ring in range(1, nrings+1): #For each ring (1, 2, 3, ..., nrings)
        bigring = df["geometry"].buffer(ringdist*ring) #Create one big buffer, for example 100 m
        smallring = df["geometry"].buffer(ringdist*(ring-1)) #Create one smalle one 90 m
        theonering = bigring.difference(smallring) #Difference the big with the small to create a ring
        rings.append(theonering) #Append the ring to the rings list
    return rings #return the list

#Create a column with the rings as a list
df["multiring"] = df.apply(lambda x: multiringbuffer(df=x, nrings=10, ringdist=100), axis=1) #Buffer the geometry 10 times, with a ring width of 100 m
df = df.explode("multiring") #Explode to create a row for each ring

df = df.set_geometry("multiring")
df = df.drop(columns=["geometry"]).rename_geometry("geometry").set_crs(crs)
#df.to_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\Delauney\multiringbuffer.shp")
```

[image]